# ListView data not showing in fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter

Here's the code that's producing unexpected results. If anyone can please guide me to what I'm doing wrong here

```
 public static class LaunchpadSectionFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_section_launchpad, container, false);

        ListView moviesList= (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.movies_list);

        ArrayAdapter<String> moviesAdapter;
        List<String> Testing = new ArrayList<String>();
        Testing.add("Hey");
        Testing.add("Hey");
        Testing.add("Hey");
        Testing.add("Hey");
        moviesAdapter= new MyAdapter(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,Testing);
        moviesList.setAdapter(moviesAdapter);


return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok after playing around a Lot going through documentation I finally found a workaround to this.
This is what I did

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

            Log.d("CreatedActivity", "LaunchpadFragment");
            ListView moviesList= (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.movies_list);
            // Gets the ListView from the View list of the parent activity
            // Gets a CursorAdapter

            ArrayAdapter<String> moviesAdapter;
            List<String> Testing = new ArrayList<String>();
            Testing.add("Hey");
            Testing.add("Hey Do");
            Testing.add("Hey It");
            Testing.add("Hey Please");
            moviesAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Testing);
            moviesList.setAdapter(moviesAdapter);
}
```

Note the over-ridden method here, it is

> onActivityCreated

Android documentation states

> If your view of the fragment is a listview that is being filled by a data adapter, you should override the onActivityCreated method and do the filling in there.

I don't have a documentation link to this blockquote though:|